# Displaying a small image inside a button or frame

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to display a small image inside a `Frame` or `Button` but the `Image` that im using its bigger than my `Button`/`Frame`and when I try to do it with `Frame` it wont display the `Image` only with the `Button` the problem being that the `Image` is way too big. How can I fix this.

Using `Button`:

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#40000000" BorderColor="#FFFFFF" CornerRadius="6" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.01*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.01*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button Image="sobremesa.png" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Ingredient"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2.8*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="https://i.imgur.com/066Iazn.png" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="CategoryImage"/>
                        <Label Text="Melão c/ Presunto" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Label Text="6.90€" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

Using `Frame`:

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#40000000" BorderColor="#FFFFFF" CornerRadius="6" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.01*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.01*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Black" x:Name="Ingredient">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="sobremesa.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2.8*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="https://i.imgur.com/066Iazn.png" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="CategoryImage"/>
                        <Label Text="Melão c/ Presunto" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Label Text="6.90€" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

[image: With <code>Button</code>]
[image: With <code>Frame</code>]

The `Image` that im trying to display in the `Frame` is in the child `Frame`.
Remember that when I try to display with `Frame` it wont display the `Image`.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `button` exactly? I can't see the `Text` for it. Why don't you use `ImageButton` or `Image` with `GestureRecognizer`?

Comment: I dont need exactly use to use Button, I just want to display the Image and later do some action for it. @ДенисЧорный

Comment: Then you should check the `ImageButton`, how it could be used.

Comment: @ДенисЧорный Yeah that worked very well. Thank you.

Comment: @ДенисЧорный One more thing I just added a GestureRecognizer to my ImageButton but when I try to click on it doesnt do anything. Im currently just trying to change its color for testing.

Comment: You don't need to add a `GestureRecognizer` to your `ImageButton`, it's for `Image`. `ImageButton` has its own event handler `Clicked`.

Comment: @ДенисЧорный True forgot that but it's the same thing.

Comment: Show the code, please, because I don't know what exactly wrong with the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193500/discussion-between---and-lol-jovem).

Comment: @ДенисЧорный Its solved, thank you for everyting and sorry for not saying anything.

Comment: Ok, happy coding))